# A set whose power set is pairwise disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you give me an example of a set whose power set is pairwise disjoint?

The problem with this for me has been that since the power set always contains the set itself, then wouldn't this mean that all sets must have some elements that are not pairwise disjoint, since the subsets of B will be contained in B and therefore for some $A_i \in 2^B$ it must be that $A_i \cap B \not = \emptyset $?

Comment: What about $\mathcal{P}(\{a\})=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$?

Comment: The other possibility is $\mathcal{P} (\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$. Anything with more than $2$ elements won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $A$ the powerset $\mathcal P(A)$ is pairwise disjoint iff $A$ has at most one element.

Proof.
If $A = \emptyset$, then $\mathcal P(A) = \{ \emptyset \}$ is pairwise disjoint. If $A = \{ * \}$ for some $*$, then $\mathcal P(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{ * \} \}$ is also pairwise disjoint.

Conversely, if there are distinct $x,y \in A$, then $\{x\}, \{x,y\} \in \mathcal P(A)$ and $\{x \} \cap \{x,y\} = \{x\} \neq \emptyset$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Wait, why does $\{x,y\} \in \mathcal P(A)$ if $A = \{\{x\}, \{y\}\}$?

Comment: @mavavilj I said, $x,y \in A$ not $\{x\}, \{y\} \in A$. So it would be $A = \{x,y \}$ and then surely $\{x\}, \{x,y\} \subseteq A$.

Comment: And technically $A\supseteq \{x,y\}$ but need not be limited to just those two elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I was referring to his specific example.